# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row when try to update with group by clause

Tags: sql, oracle

```
update ET_BP_FACT f
set BUDGET =  (select  sum(BUDGET) 
from ET_BP_FACT,ET_BP_GL_ACCOUNT
where ET_BP_FACT.GL_ACCOUNT_ID=ET_BP_GL_ACCOUNT.GL_ACCOUNT_ID
 group by GL_SUB_ID )
where GL_ACCOUNT_ID in (select  TOTAL_ELEMENT from  ET_BP_FACT f ,ET_BP_GL_ACCOUNT g 
where f.GL_ACCOUNT_ID=g.GL_ACCOUNT_ID ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want correlated subqueries:

```
update ET_BP_FACT f
    set BUDGET = (select sum(BUDGET) 
                  from ET_BP_GL_ACCOUNT a
                  where f.GL_ACCOUNT_ID = a.GL_ACCOUNT_ID
                 )
   where f.GL_ACCOUNT_ID in (select g.GL_ACCOUNT_ID
                             from ET_BP_GL_ACCOUNT g 
                             where f.GL_ACCOUNT_ID = g.GL_ACCOUNT_ID
                            ) ;
```

I have no idea what `TOTAL_ELEMENT` is being used for, so I didn't include it in this version of the query.

Comment: but sum(BUDGET) returns null ,it cannot retrive data from ET_BP_FACT f ,so no rows updated yet